# How can I prevent hacking like $remove in AngularFire

Tags: angularfire

All:

I am pretty new to AngularFire, when I follow tutorial to do a simple todo app, I wonder how can I only allow user to add new todo, but not delete. Basically I do not want client side hack to destroy my data. Like user opens console and manually call $remove API, how can I prevent that?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

To prevent clients from performing unwanted CRUD operations on your Firebase database, you need to define [database rules](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/).

Rules are defined in a JSON structure and can reference the current `auth` information. For example, if you are storing user information in database under `/users/<uid>`, the following rule would grant each user read/write access to their own information and read access to other users' information:

```
{
  "rules": {
    "users": {
      ".read": "auth != null"
      "$uid": {
        ".write": "auth != null && auth.uid == $uid"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Rules can also reference data that's already in the database, so it's possible to allow writes only if there is no existing data at a particular key - that is, you can prevent updates.

Similarly, rules can reference the new data that is to be stored, so it's possible to check that new data has been specified - that is, you can prevent deletes.

A rule like this would allow todos (stored under `/todos/<uid>/<todoId>`) to be created, but neither updated nor deleted:

```
...
"todos": {
  "$uid": {
    ".read": "auth != null && auth.uid == $uid",
    "$todoId": {
      ".write": "auth != null && auth.uid == $uid && data.val() == null && newData.val() != null"
    }
  }
}
...
```

Maintaining rule definitions in the JSON structure can become difficult; you might find Firebase's [Bolt](https://github.com/firebase/bolt) tool useful for defining more complicated rules.